# validate form on MVC4 but avoid submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

i have a set of fields on a view on my aplication, i need to validate those fields before refreshing a jqgrid, but i need to prevent the submit functiuon to post to the server, i only need the form to validate the fields and then call a jquery funcition. but i dont know how to do it.

until now i have somthing like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.scheduledIdPersonaSeleccionada)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.scheduledIdPersonaSeleccionada)

   <button type="submit" class="BTNTexto" id="buscarPorPersona">
         <img src="~/Images/Icons/search.png" />
         <span>@Html.Raw(Res_String.BuscarTurnos)</span>
   </button>
}
```

and a jquery function called `reloadGrid()`, so i need that when i press the button the validation cheks the fields (1 on my example) then if all is ok call my `reloadGrid()` function, also my validation is not working

pd jquery validation libraries are loaded ok

Comment: $('#buscarPorPersona').onclick(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        reloadGrid();
    });

Comment: If you want help with client-side code, you have to also show the code as seen by the client, including the HTML markup.

Answer (score 1):

there are 3 ways that we use.  First use @Rosdi's code and add your validation to the event

```
if($('#scheduledIdPersonaSeleccionada').val() == ""){
    alert('something');
}
```

you can also use an ajax call back to the server and send the fields that you want to validate

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@(Url.Action("Action", "Controller"))",
    data: { data: 'data', data1: 'data1'},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        if(result.Success){

        }else{

        }
    }
});
```

you mentioned avoiding submit but we also use that.  Put an attribute on the field

```
[Required]
public string scheduledIdPersonaSeleccionada { get; set; }
```

and then in your controller check model state

```
if(ModelState.IsValid){

}else{
    return View(model);
}
```

the third way is the easiest since it sends the model back for you and the checking is done with the attributes you have sent.  Hopefully this helps.